What's the intuition behind the construction of $X$ in Brezis' theorem 7.3
I'm reading Brezis' Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations. Theorem 7.3 says:
Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $F:E\rightarrow E$ be a Lipschitz map, i.e., there is a constant $L$ such that
$$
\|Fu-Fc\|\le L\|u-v\|,\ \forall u,v\in E.
$$
Then given any $u_0\in E$, there exists a unique solution $u\in C^1([0,+\infty);E)$ of the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{du}{dt}(t)=Fu(t)\ \text{on}\ [0,+\infty),\\
u(0)=u_0.
\end{cases}
$$
In proof he turns to study the integral equation
$$
u(t)=u_0+\int_0^tF(u(s))ds=:(\Phi u)(t)
$$
and he constructs $X$ as follow:
$$
X=\{u\in C([0,+\infty);E);\ \sup_{t\ge0}e^{-kt}\|u(t)\|<\infty\}.
$$
then he uses Banach fixed point theorem on $X$ to prove the existence of solution for the integral equation above.
My question is that what's the intuition behind the construction of $X$? I know that if $F$ is a constant map, then the solution should be $u(t)=e^{tF}u_0$, which more of less explains why $e^{-kt}$ appears in the definition of $X$. But this explanation maybe far-fetched. Can $X$ be any other form?

I think your idea is completely right. You know the dynamics for $F$ constant, you hope the same holds for Lipschitz $F$, and start the proof. If it works, your hope was valid, otherwise you must try something else.

Thanks for your comment! I've considered this question again and found that when $F$ is constant, then $u_0=e^{-tF}u(t)$, which may suggest that $e^{-tF}u(t)$ should be independent of $t$. Thus we try to apply $|\cdot|_{C([0,+\infty);E)}$ on $e^{-kt}u(t)$ and see what happens. But I wonder what if the condition of $F$ is weaker?(like $F$ is only continuous or bounded) Is there any default procedure for us to construct work space like $X$, or we can just guess how $X$ may look like by assuming $F$ to be constant and to see whether the proof holds?

Well, for $F$ a bounded linear operator, the matrix exponential $\sum_k\frac{t^kF^K}{k!}$ is well defined and again a bounded linear operator. This should tell you a lot about the solution.

Thanks a lot, I forgot $e^{-tF}$ can be written in this way.

The space is defined in that way because you know already that for any solution the sup is finite. You have $d/dt |u(t)|\leq |F(0)|+|F(u(t))-F(0)|\leq |F(0)|+L|u(t)|$, so Gronwall's lemma gives you $|u(t)|\leq e^{tL} |u_0|+|F(0)|/L\cdot(e^{tL}-1)$.

Oh! So by the result of Gronwall's lemma $e^{-tL}|u(t)|$ can be controlled by a constant. Now $|\Phi u-\Phi v|$ can be controlled by $\int_0^tL|u-v|ds=\int_0^tLe^{sL}e^{-sL}|u-v|ds$. If $e^{-sL}|u-v|$ can be taken out from integral, then $e^{-tL}|\Phi u-\Phi v|$ can be controlled by a constant $C$ multiplying $e^{-tL}|u-v|$. By modifying $L$ to $k$ in $e^{-tL}|u|$ we can make $C<1$, thus fixed point theorem can be applied. I got it, thanks very much!
